# Flex Listening an event in Main.mxml while in a component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, event-handling

So, I have an event, which I have dispatched in my main.mxml:

```
var evt:UserEvent = new UserEvent(UserEvent.USERINFORMATION);
evt.userVO = storeObject;
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

I can listen for it while in my navigation.mxml file, by using

```
this.parentApplication.addEventListener(UserEvent.USERINFORMATION, onInfo);
```

But in other component, I can not listen for it, even trying the same as I did in navigation.mxml.

tracing it back gives me an undefined.

the second component is in a viewstack in navigation.

Comment: Can you post a toy example? What type of component is the latter? Is it a DisplayObject?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the following in the viewStack component:

```
Application.application.addEventListener(UserEvent.USERINFORMATION, onInfo); //Flex 3
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(UserEvent.USERINFORMATION, onInfo); //Flex 4
```

Sure let us know if this works